# How do I find out if all FK references in the child table are present in the parent table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table `user (id, name ...)` and `user_emails (id, user_id, email_id, type)`. There was no foreign key enforcement between these tables initially. I would like to know all rows in `user_emails` which don't have a corresponding `user_id` in the user table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`select * from user_emails where user_id not in (select id from user)` this would probably give you the answer.

Answer (score 1):

LEFT JOIN from the child to the parent where the parent PK is null. It means there was no JOIN record to find.